# How to write Podfile (kept in repository A) to link to podspec present under a folder in different remote repository B?

Tags: git, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

Sample pod file:

```
target ‘test’ do

 pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => ‘path to remote git/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'

  pod 'GLog', :podspec => ‘path to remote git/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'

  pod 'Folly', :podspec => ‘path to remote git/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

end
```

I am trying to call podspec like `<path to remote git>` followed by path to podspec. But it's not working as expected. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I've used is a path to the podspec's directory in a local checkout:

`pod 'GLog', :podspec => ‘absolute path to cloned git repo/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs'`